# Putting multiple markers to google map, what might be the problem?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to display markers for each address i have in my database. I'm storing the addresses in javascript array, and geocoding them, to display a marker on map for each of them. The addresses gets stored in the array, but unfortunately only the last address gets a marker on map.

```
 <script>
var addresses = [];
        <?php
            if(is_array($fetchData)){      
            $sn=1;
            foreach($fetchData as $data){
        
            $post = $data['post'];
            $city = $data['city'];
            $street = $data['street'];
            $number = $data['number'];
                            
        ?>
    var address = '<?php echo $data['post'] . ' ' . $data['city'] . ' ' . $data['street'] . ' ' . $data['number']; ?>';
      
    
    addresses.push(address);

    var geocoder;
      var map;
      
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          
        });
        var i = 0;
        geocoder[i] = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        codeAddress(geocoder, map);
      }

      function codeAddress(geocoder, map) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
              
            });
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
      
      i++;
   
<?php
    $sn++;}}else{ ?>
<?php
}?>
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

I was thinking about indexing the 'geocoder' and doing 'i++;' at the end of the loop, but it didn't work yet.

Comment: Why don't you pass all the data to Javascript and make the loop there? This code produces far too much unneccessary javascript code...

Comment: No errors in your console?

Comment: @HonkderHase tell me how to, and i would gladly! :D

Comment: @brombeer 'Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined' is the only error at the 'i++;' part

Comment: The way this looks is that you are declaring the `initMap` function and associated within the loop just so that each address can be geocoded?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius exactly

Comment: Is `$fetchData` from a database query?

Comment: it is, the php parts are fetching the addresses from the database

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? You could start explaining why you print all that JS code multiple times. Usually, you don't need to print a new defintion of `initMap`  for **each** address item

Comment: Separate the data from the code. Write PHP that introduces the data as a JS variable, rewrite the JS code to take data from the variable.  edit: like the professor shows in his answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would run the db query and convert that PHP result into a variable that can be processed in Javascript. JSON is perfect for that purpose -  easy to generate in PHP and easy to process in Javascript after.

You might consider approaching like this, untested, example perhaps:

```
<script>
    <?php
        
        // convert db results array into JSON and echo as a js variable.
        printf('const addresses=%s;', json_encode( is_array( $fetchData ) ? $fetchData : [] ) );
                 
    ?>
    /*
        create the map and declare once the geocoder etc
    */
    function initMap() {
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 8
        });
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        let codeAddress=( address )=>{
            geocoder.geocode({'address': address }, function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    map.setCenter( results[0].geometry.location );
                    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });     
        };
        /*
            iterate through the JSON data to call the geocoder function for each result
        */
        Object.keys( addresses ).forEach(key=>{
            let obj=addresses[ key ];
            let address=`${obj.post} ${obj.city} ${obj.street} ${obj.number}`;
            
            codeAddress.call( this, address );
        });
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: It's perfectly working! Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Excellent - glad I was able to offer some guidance. Good luck